# Specify dataframe column dtype during assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, is it possible to set the dtype of a column during assignment? What works is changing it afterwards, e.g.

```
df["file"] = file
df["file"] = df["file"].astype("category")
```

However, I have some large dataframes where this `file` column barely fits into memory but would fit much more easily as a `categorical` dtype. There it would be convenient if I could declare them as categorical already during assignment. I envision something like

```
df.add_column(name="file", data=file, dtype="category")
```

Is that possible?

Comment: what is `file`?

Comment: Yes you can look at `df.convert_dtypes()` and `df.infer_dtypes()` as well!

Comment: `file` is a string or a list of string that point to the source of the data. The strings are long but only have a few unique values so the category dtype should save memory.

Comment: @jtlz2 `convert_dtypes()` sounds cool if it actually optimizes the dtype, but doesn't it require the column to be created first?

Comment: @LimaKilo But you already have the column yourself too - it's called "file": `df["file"] = file`. @mozway is right - you need then to fix it when you read in the values of `file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `file` is an iterable, you can pass a Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})
file = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']

df['file'] = pd.Series(file, index=df.index, dtype='category')

   col file
0    0    A
1    1    B
2    2    C
3    3    A
4    4    A
5    5    B
6    6    C
```

If `file` is a string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})
file = 'filename'

df['file'] = pd.Series(file, index=df.index, dtype='category')

   col      file
0    0  filename
1    1  filename
2    2  filename
3    3  filename
4    4  filename
5    5  filename
6    6  filename
```

dtypes:

```
# df.dtypes

col        int64
file    category
dtype: object
```

##### using Categoricals before a [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

If your goal is to `concat`, then you must use an homogeneous [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})

dfs = [df1, df2]
files = ['filename1', 'filename2']

myfiles_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=files)

for df, f in zip(dfs, files):
    df['file'] = pd.Series(f, index=df1.index, dtype=myfiles_cat)

out = pd.concat(dfs)

print(out.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
col        int64
file    category
dtype: object
```

Comment: Isn't the point that the variable `file` won't fit in memory?

Comment: @jtlz2 if OP can do `df["file"] = file ; df["file"] = df["file"].astype("category")` then this should work

Comment: In the OP's comments, they state: "doesn't it require the column to be created first?" - So I think they are saying it can't?

Comment: IF OP can fit `file` in memory, then why doesn't their `df["file"] = df["file"].astype("category")` work?

Comment: @jtlz2 I understood the question as "*I assign my data this way, but as I have a large dataset I'd prefer to have a categorical. Can I directly assign a categorical in one step or do I need to convert after assignment?*" not as "*this code doesn't work, is there a more efficient method?*"

Comment: If `df["file"]` will barely fit in memory, then why would `file`?

Comment: @mozway exactly, that's what I meant. There's two aspects. One is that if I already have the variable `file`, the corresponding dataframe column will need additional memory. The other one is that in my current script, `file` is actually just one string that will be duplicated to each row, so that when I later concat the `df` with others, I can trace which rows came from which file.

Comment: @LimaKilo, ok then the above approach should work with a string, **however** after `concat` **this will convert the categorical back to `object`**! Since a categorical is just an integer array with a mapping, I'd recommend to use an integer ID to trace the file, eventually mapping the integer to categorical **after** `concat` (if needed).

Comment: Or use a single categorical dtype that contains all possible filenames (see updated answer)

Comment: @mozway oh, the `concat` caveat is something I did not notice until now! I think I indeed use a separate index to mark the source files, even though that means not having all data in one place, but it is definitely easier than making sure to know all possible categories before in my case.

Comment: and the `pd.Series()` approach works well without the concat problem. I'm accepting this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
# From @mozway
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})
file = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']

df['file'] = pd.Categorical(file)
```

Output:

```
>>> df.dtypes
col        int64
file    category
dtype: object
```

How to deal with [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)

Comment: Isn't the point that the variable `file` won't fit in memory?